# C: return a value from a recursive call

Tags: c, recursion

```
int find(char* a, trie_node* node, int result){//need to make sure a is not NULL at beginning
    int i,temp;
    if ((a != NULL && a[0] !='\n') && node->children[a[0] - 97] == NULL)
    {
        result = 0;//not found any children satisfied the requirement
    }
    else if ((a != NULL && a[0] !='\n') && node->children[a[0] - 97] != NULL){
        temp = a[0];
        a++;
        find(a, node->children[temp - 97], result);
    } else{//a == NULL, which means end of the find procedure, just return the num_children
        result = node->num_children; //most inner one
    }
    return result;
}
```

I am trying to return the result from this function. Since it is a strict c program, I need a return statement at end of the function.

After I trace it in gdb, the most inner function call return correct number to result. However, the value of result is lost during back to outer function. So as a result, this function will return 0 which is wrong. How could I return and keep the value from the innermost call?

Comment: Why does your function have a `result` parameter? Its value is never used.

Comment: @melpomene originally, I don't have that in add function. However, since I need to return result at end of the function, I thought it would be better to have a parameter as a global variable which can store value from inner function. That's why I add result.

Comment: Parameters are local variables. "*a parameter as a global variable*" doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yea, I got that after I traced this code in gdb and found out that it was not acting as global variables. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: What is the magic number `97` for? Is that `'a'`?

Answer (score 2):

you just need to add the return statement.  You don't need the result parameter at all either.  Try this re-write;

```
int find(char* a, trie_node* node) {
    //need to make sure a is not NULL at beginning
    int i,temp;
    if ((a != NULL && a[0] !='\n') && node->children[a[0] - 97] == NULL)
    {
        return 0;//not found any children satisfied the requirement
    }
    else if ((a != NULL && a[0] !='\n') && 
             node->children[a[0] - 97] != NULL)
    {
        temp = a[0];
        a++;
        return find(a, node->children[temp - 97]);
    } 
    //a == NULL, which means end of the find procedure, just return the num_children
    return node->num_children; //most inner one
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! Where do I add this

Comment: Although correct I downvoted because that hurts the style of the function (see another answer). Better to assign that recursive value to `result = ...`

Comment: @WeatherVane Actually it may be better to not have the unused result parameter...

Comment: @WeatherVane Ok I've taken your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your question, but I think this is what you want to do. May be you forgot to catch the return value in the block of second `if` when you call the function. (But why are you passing that result parameter to the function?   I think that has no use there.)

```
int find(char* a, trie_node* node, int result){//need to make sure a is not NULL at beginning

    int i,temp;
    if ((a != NULL && a[0] !='\n') && node->children[a[0] - 97] == NULL)
    {
        result = 0;//not found any children satisfied the requirement
    }
    else if ((a != NULL && a[0] !='\n') && node->children[a[0] - 97] != NULL){
        temp = a[0];
        a++;
       result= find(a, node->children[temp - 97], result);
    } else{//a == NULL, which means end of the find procedure, just return the num_children
        result = node->num_children; //most inner one
    }
    return result;
}
```